# Fitting image within div with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fit images of different size in the `div` which I have declared.I am making use of [Bootstrap Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/).In the modal body I have added the code which gets images from backend.

I have placed those images in a div and tried to adjust those images within the div.

**Problem I am facing**

The width of all div is same when I check with `inspect element` but the height of div is proportional to the height of image.I dont know why that is happening
(When I do `inspect element`.If I get axb for an div then value of a is same for all `div` but value of b depends on image and is different for all `div`)

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-body">
        {% for file in brands %}
        {% load static %}
            <div class="outerdiv"><img class="img-fl" src="{% get_static_prefix %}images/brands/{{file}}" alt=""></div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal-body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

.outerdiv {
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  display:inline-block;
}



.img-fl{

    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;

}
```

Entire modal code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Add More Brands</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="removeclass()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        {% for file in brands %}
        {% load static %}
            <div class="outerdiv"><img class="img-fl" src="{% get_static_prefix %}images/brands/{{file}}" alt=""></div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="removeclass()">Close</button>
        <button id="add-image" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Brand</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is advised not to shrink the image height because it will change the aspect ratio of the image and leads to the bad user experience but if you want to fit the image with in a `div` then you can go with the background image property `background-size: auto;`.

Comment: Should I put that in `.img-fl` ?

Comment: No on the `.outerdiv`

Comment: My outer div is of the form `.outerdiv {
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  display:inline-block;
  background-size: auto;
}` But still I am getting same results

Comment: with the above code u also have to update the background url in JS to see different image for different `div` and you can remove the image inside the `div`

Comment: I am fairly new to all this. I have Two doubts I have 1)Where can I do that  2)I get images dynamically from backend with the above code.

Comment: So basically since it is a modal you'll be triggering some function to update the modal content, so in that function instead of changing the `<img>` you have to change the `background url` of `outediv` with the dynamic image `url's`

Answer (score 1):

if you want the parent div to be of a given height relative to the modal div, then you must add `relative` property to it, you can even use `min-height` and `max-height` to make it more flexible to your need. also note that the `modal div's` `height` must be set to an `absolute value` and not to a `relative value` since it is not declared `relative`. you wrote `height: 100%`, **100% of what?**

```
.modal-body {
    width: 100%;
    /**
    display: relative; use this one if the parent element to the modal body
    has an absolute height set on it.
    height: 100%;
    */
    height: 500px; /**absolute value for height, if not relative to a parent div*/
}

.outerdiv {
  min-height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  /**
  max-height: 90%;
  */
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
}



.img-fl{

    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: My Outerdiv is of the form `.outerdiv {
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;

}
` Still the same results as before

Comment: check the edit, and use it. it will solve your issue

Comment: Now the images are going out of modal with the edit.Modal height seems to be less.The problem is I cant even hardcode the height.I dont know how much image would I get and accordingly the modal should height should grow

Comment: With `height=100%` I mean to say that whatever height `modal-body` is having will be 100% .Height of div will be relative to this height of modal

Comment: I have updated the question with code for entire modal

Comment: if you dont know the number of images, then simply add `min-height: 40px` to the image div element. and not relative to the modal. . replace 40px with the height you prefer

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this to your CSS



    .outerdiv{height:30%;
width:30%;}

    .img-f1{height:100%; 
    width:100%;
    Object-fit: cover;
    }
```

Or you can refer to more object-fit values like contain, fill.

Comment: This is not at all helping.It makes images to appear very weird than before

Comment: Bootstrap modal have property of height auto that's why images getting weired .setting height of your outerdiv will surely get your answer